# What is google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I know that `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize)` function adds a listener to the window object, which as soon as the load event is triggered (i.e. "the page has finished loading") executes the function initialize.
But i have some more doubts like

1. Here we use "Window" object . can we use further object instead of this window object or it is compulsory to use "window".
2. which type of event we can use instead of "load" event.........

Answer (score 4):

It's a cross-browser-wrapper for the handling of DOM-events.

You may use it for DOM-Objects like e.g. nodes/elements, documents and windows. You may use any [DOMevent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events) you want to.

Beyond that you may also use it to add custom events to custom objects:

```js
var  something={};
google.maps.event.addDomListener(something,'someevent',function(){
  alert('custom event');
});
google.maps.event.trigger(something,'someevent');
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3"></script>
```